# Printing to screen on a GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, console.writeline

I am very new to programming, specifically creating GUIs; I've previously only written console programs in C#, and am now attempting to build a game with XNA. Could anyone help me by letting me know how to print to the screen in a GUI? I'm currently trying variations of `System.Console.WriteLine("");`, but will not print to screen. The code I am using is below. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

`ResourceCounter.cs`:

```
      public ResourceCounter(Vector2 pos, GameTime gameTime)`
       {
        position = pos;
        over = false;
        clicked = false;
        gameTime = new GameTime();`

        currentTime += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; 
        System.Console.WriteLine("Resources: ", pSourceCount);

        if (currentTime >= countDuration)
        {
            pSourceCount++;
            **System.Console.WriteLine("Resources: ", pSourceCount);**
        }
        if (pSourceCount >= limit)
        {
            pSourceCount = 0;//Reset the counter;

        }


    }
```

and in my main `GameScreen.cs` class:

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState();
        menu.Update(mState, cursor, gameTime);

        if (menu.currentstate == State.campaign)
        {
            campaign.Update(pTower);
            //campaign.Update(eTower);
            **System.Console.WriteLine("Resources: ", pSourceCount);**
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`SpriteBatch.DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673.aspx) method for rendering text with XNA.

When you print text with `System.Console.WriteLine` it is written to the standard output stream. The data in this stream is then presented through the console. Your game window takes no notice of this at all.

---

### Text Rendering

It's fair to say that everything you draw to your game window consists of (textured) triangles. Text is no exception. A single character is rendered using a quad (rectangle), that again consists of 2 triangles.

The text `XNA!` would be drawn using a total of 4 sprites (8 triangles), one sprite for every character:

[image: text rendered in "Fill" and "Wireframe" mode]

### Bitmap Font

Common font formats store the characters as vectors. For [bitmap fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts) (the kind of font usually used in games) the actual type face is stored in one or more bitmaps (textures). This method is much faster, as the character shapes themselves are *already rasterized* and only have to be sampled from the texture. The obvious drawback is, that the characters all come in a *fixed size*. You need one bitmap font per font face per size per weight.

This is a sprite map for the Arial font, size 20, standard weight:

[image]

For drawing a certain character, the renderer has to know where on the bitmap the character is located. As you can see in the image above, each character occupies a non overlapping rectangular area. The dimensions of those rectangles can be stored in an additional text or XML file.

For example, this could be a definition of the `A` character for the sprite map above:

```
<char id="65" x="235" y="47" width="12" height="13" xoffset="0" yoffset="3" xadvance="11" page="0" />
```

- `id` is the ASCII value (A=65)
- `x` and `y` are the position of the top left corner
- `width` and `height` are the size of the rectangle
- `xoffset` and `yoffset` is the offset on screen
- `xadvance` is the distance to the preceding character
- `page` is the index of the bitmap that contains the character

### Conclusion

Text rendering for games is not as trivial as one would assume. XNA *greatly* simplifies the process with the `SpriteBatch` class. A summary of the steps involved:

- Convert a standard font to a bitmap font
- Load the font files in your game application
- Create the sprites for a given string
- Render the sprites to the screen

---

The font example was created with a free [Bitmap Font Generator](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/).

Comment: I knew it was something to do with SpriteBatch! Just couldn't figure out the correct connection. Yeah I knew I was wrong with Console.WriteLine (hint's in the first part, Console!) but just could not see around it. Thanks very much, it's functioning correctly now. Sorry for the silly question!

Comment: I don't think it's a silly question. Text rendering is such an essential part of most applications; the high complexity of the problem is surprising at first. Your confusion in regards to the console is totally understandable in my opinion.